# How to get value of global variable in another file after updating it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python to create a script where I want to get a value of my global variable.

So I created a little example to explain my problem:

#### `getFile.py`

```
import time

from loopFile import startLoop, getValue
from multiprocessing import Process

def valueGetter():
    while True:
        print("My value is " + getValue())
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Process(target=startLoop)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=valueGetter)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    start()
```

#### `loopFile.py`

```
import time
myValue = 0

def increment():
    global myValue
    myValue = myValue + 1
    print(myValue)

def getValue():
    return str(myValue)

def startLoop():
    while True:
        increment()
        time.sleep(1)
```

If you try to run this program you will get this output:

```
python getFile.py
1
My value is 0
2
3
4
5
6
My value is 0
7
8
9
10
11
My value is 0
12
```

I'm a C# developer and I just want to create a "public variable" like (maybe a "static" variable) to access the value. But I don't know how it apparently works...

Comment: Every process has its own memory. Use multithreading if you want to share memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass your variable `myValue` by argument of the process. Something like this:

```py
from loopFile import *
...

num = Value('d', myValue)
p = Process(target=f, args=(num))
```

And then, to see this work, you need to change the function to receive the argument also. Be aware of concurrency to this shared variable. see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)